# Is postgresql running and where

Tags: postgresql

I am really lost on this one.  My Django application used to work and then suddenly stopped working, when I start the server I get this

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Fair enough, so now I want to check if postgres is running and on what port.  This is where I am lost as I can't find it running.  The following suggests that it is:

service postgresql status

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-11-16 13:29:37 GMT; 6s ago
Process: 7023 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 7023 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

This gives me some information
ps aux | grep -i postgres

```
myuser+  7985  0.0  0.0  14228   976 pts/17   S+   13:38   0:00 grep --color=auto -i postgres
```

But I am unclear what it means, this gives me port details

sudo netstat -plunt

For example

```
roto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1381/smbd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      791/redis-server 0.
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2415/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1211/nginx.conf 
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      841/dnsmasq
```

The config file here: /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

Says that Postgres should run on 5432

My summary is that Postgres isn't running, but I am unsure where else to look to see any more information.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Grant

Comment: The `ps aux | grep -i postgres` command tells you `postgres` isn't running. It just returned the `grep` process that you were running to find it. `service postgresql` tells you the service is `active (exited)` which means `systemd` did what it had to do but doesn't know if there's a daemon to monitor (which, apparently, there isn't). Have you tried just restarting `postgres` with something like `service postgresql restart`? Are there errors preventing it from starting (a good place to start would be the logs, usually located in `/var/log/postgresql`)

Comment: Have you checked the log ? If you do not know where the log files are, take a look at [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html)

Comment: Interestingly there are no new log files\records created, I can see some old ones (from when it did work) but no new ones.  Is there somewhere to see logs before the postgres logs?

Comment: I got a bit further with this.  I can start Postgres like this - /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf - that pushes everything to the console\logs, but not using service postgresql restart